# TypeError: EmailVerificationTokenGenerator.make_token() missing 1 required positional argument: 'contact_form'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, email-verification

I am trying to build an email server for my website. I have a contact form and when you pass it, the server sends a verification link to email address specified in the form. Also, a response after submitting the contact form includes a unique link to re-send new verification link. On the surface my implementation looks fine, but now I am stuck on this error:

TypeError at /api/contact/
EmailVerificationTokenGenerator.make_token() missing 1 required positional argument: 'contact_form'.

"[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV4Cf.png)

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_str
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import ContactFormSerializer
from .verification import EmailVerificationTokenGenerator
from .models import ContactForm 
from email_server.permissions import CanResendVerificationLink
from rest_framework import status
from django.urls import reverse
import secrets
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


# Base Mixin
class EmailVerificationMixin:
    def _send_email_verification(self, contact_form):
        subject = 'Verify Your Email'
        uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(contact_form.pk))
        verification_token = EmailVerificationTokenGenerator().make_token(contact_form)
        verification_link = self._get_verification_link(contact_form, uidb64, verification_token)
        body = render_to_string(
            'email_verification.html',
            {
                'verification_link': verification_link,
            }
        )
        email = EmailMessage(subject=subject, body=body, to=[contact_form.email])
        email.send()

    def _get_verification_link(self, contact_form, uidb64, token):
        current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
        verification_url = reverse('activate', kwargs={'uidb64': uidb64, 'token': token})
        verification_link = f'{self.request.scheme}://{current_site.domain}{verification_url}'
        return verification_link

    def _get_resend_verification_link(self, contact_form):
        current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
        resend_token = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)  # Generate a new resend token
        resend_verification_url = reverse('resend_verification', kwargs={'pk': contact_form.pk, 'token': resend_token})
        resend_verification_link = f'{self.request.scheme}://{current_site.domain}{resend_verification_url}'
        return resend_verification_link


# API Views

class ContactFormAPIView(EmailVerificationMixin, APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ContactFormSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        contact_form = serializer.save()

        self._send_email_verification(contact_form)

        response_data = {
            'detail': 'Email verification link sent.',
            'resend_verification_link': self._get_resend_verification_link(contact_form),
        }

        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    
class ResendVerificationLinkAPIView(EmailVerificationMixin, APIView):
    permission_classes = [CanResendVerificationLink]
    
    def post(self, request, pk, token):
        contact_form = get_object_or_404(ContactForm, pk=pk)
        
        if contact_form.is_email_verified:
            return Response({'detail': 'Email is already verified.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if not self._is_valid_resend_token(contact_form, token):
            return Response({'detail': 'Invalid token.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        self._send_email_verification(contact_form)

        response_data = {
            'detail': 'Email verification link has been re-sent. Please check your email.',
            'resend_verification_link': self._get_resend_verification_link(contact_form),
        }

        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    def _is_valid_resend_token(self, contact_form, token):
        return token == contact_form.resend_token
```

verification.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils.crypto import constant_time_compare
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta


class EmailVerificationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    token_duration = timedelta(minutes=30)

    def _make_hash_value(self, contact_form, timestamp):
        return (
            str(contact_form.is_email_verified) +
            str(contact_form.pk) +
            str(timestamp)
        )

    def make_token(self, contact_form):
        timestamp = int(timezone.now().timestamp())
        hash_value = self._make_hash_value(contact_form, timestamp)
        return self._make_token_with_timestamp(hash_value, timestamp)


    def check_token(self, contact_form, token):
        if not (contact_form and token):
            return False

        try:
            timestamp = int(token.split('-')[-1])
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            return False

        if self._is_token_expired(timestamp):
            return False

        expected_token = self._make_token_with_timestamp(self._make_hash_value(contact_form, timestamp), timestamp)
        return constant_time_compare(token, expected_token)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import SubmittedFormsViewSet
from email_server.views import ContactFormAPIView, ActivateAPIView, ResendVerificationLinkAPIView
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'list', SubmittedFormsViewSet, basename='contact_form')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('contact/', ContactFormAPIView.as_view(), name='contact_form'),
    path('resend-verification/<slug:token>/', ResendVerificationLinkAPIView.as_view(), name='resend_verification'),
    path('activate/<str:uidb64>/<slug:token>/', ActivateAPIView.as_view(), name='activate'),
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from .verification import EmailVerificationTokenGenerator
import secrets

class ContactForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    submitted_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    verification_token = models.UUIDField(default=EmailVerificationTokenGenerator().make_token, editable=False)
    resend_token = models.UUIDField(default=secrets.token_urlsafe(32), editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Contact Form'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Contact Forms'
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['email']),
            models.Index(fields=['submitted_at']),
            models.Index(fields=['is_email_verified']),
        ]
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ContactForm


class ContactFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactForm
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['submitted_at', 'is_validated', 'is_email_verified']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email')
        name = attrs.get('name')

        if not email:   
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Email is required")

        if not name:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Name is required")
        
        if ContactForm.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Email already exists")
        
        attrs['is_validated'] = True
        
        return attrs

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        return ContactForm.objects.create(**self.validated_data)
```

I cannot really think anymore XD
I will appreciate any help and ideas.

Email verification and re-sending worked for me once, but I needed to do some fixes so that each time the links are unique for both re-sending and verification, tokens have expiration time and invalidate after new links are generated.

I tried many thing including using default make_token method, and then I tried overwriting it, changed my ContactFormAPIView many times in order to pass self and contact_form correctly. But nothing worked for me.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of errors, as they can be unclear and cause misreadings. Include the full error in the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set your function as default for your form field here:

```py
verification_token = models.UUIDField(default=EmailVerificationTokenGenerator().make_token, editable=False)
```

If you need to know the instance for generating your token, you can override save method of your model:

```py
class ContactForm(...):
    ...

    def save(**kwargs):
        if self.pk is None and not self.verification_token:
            self.verification_token = EmailVerificationTokenGenerator().make_token(contact_form=self)
            
        super().save(**kwargs)
```